# how to get numeric value from string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This will alert 23.

```
alert(parseInt('23 asdf'));
```

But this will not alert 23 but alerts NaN

```
alert(parseInt('asdf 23'));
```

How can I get number from like **`'asd98'`**?

Comment: what behaviour is intended when you have a string which contains multiple numbers ? e.g `"a24b30c90"`

Comment: I want to get number value and set it to other element.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a regex to get the first integer :

```
var num = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/),10)
```

If you want to parse any number (not just a positive integer, for example "asd -98.43") use

```
var num = str.match(/-?\d+\.?\d*/)
```

Now suppose you have more than one integer in your string :

```
var str = "a24b30c90";
```

Then you can get an array with

```
var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
```

Result : `[24, 30, 90]`

For the fun and for Shadow Wizard, here's a solution without regular expression for strings containing only one integer (it could be extended for multiple integers) :

```
var num = [].reduce.call(str,function(r,v){ return v==+v?+v+r*10:r },0);
```

Comment: Usually not a fan of regex but looks like not much choice in this case. Nice! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You **do** have a choice. Do you like my edit ? ;)

Comment: That last code block is beautiful, but it *terrifies* me for some reason...(no, I have no idea why.)

Comment: @DavidThomas Well... I would not accept it in one of my applications without strong justifications...

Comment: Lol! Never intended for such a thing but glad I was part of this! ;)

Comment: Yeah, it *felt* like being clever purely for the *sake* of being clever (and to prove there *are* alternatives to regex); but I'm not convinced that's what worried me about it. Seriously, I have *no* idea why, but, regardless: +1 =)

Answer (score 3):

```
parseInt('asd98'.match(/\d+/))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function toNumeric(string) {
    return parseInt(string.replace(/\D/g, ""), 10);
}
```

Comment: You still have to parse it to get a number instead of a string. And it works only for a limited set of characters while you could have something more general with `/\D/g`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use regular expression to extract the number.

```
var mixedTextAndNumber= 'some56number';
var justTheNumber = parseInt(mixedTextAndNumber.match(/\d+/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = +('asd98'.replace(/[a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));
```